# Moduli space about $CP^{N-1}$ and $T^* CP^{N-1}$.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, moduli-space, mirror-symmetry

For complex $\phi$ in $U(1)$ gauge theory, we have
\begin{align}
|\phi_1|^2 + |\phi_2|^2 +\cdots |\phi_N|^2 =r
\end{align}
This equation $|\phi|^2=r$, describes  sphere $S^{2N-1}$. Dividing the space of this solution by the gauge group $U(1)$ we obtain that the moduli space for $\phi$ which  is $\mathbf{CP}^{N-1}$

---

Here what i want to extend this idea to following equations 
 For same complex $\phi$ in $U(1)$ gauge theory, for given this equation 
\begin{align}
|\phi_1|^2 + |\phi_2|^2 \cdots +|\phi_N|^2 -|\phi_{N+1}|^2 - |\phi_{N+2}|^2 \cdots - |\phi_{2N}|^2      =r
\end{align}

The results for this moduli space is known as $T^* \mathbf{CP}^{N-1}$ where $T^*$ represents cotangent bundle.

Here i want to know why this space is $T^* \mathbf{CP}^{N-1}$.

Can anyone give some explanation about this?

---

In Kentaro hori et al's [*Mirror symmetry*](http://www.claymath.org/library/monographs/cmim01c.pdf) textbook, i found some interesting remarks seems to related with this problem. 
For four matter fields with charge $1,1,-1,-1$, the vacua equation can be reduced to 
\begin{align}
|\phi_1|^2 + |\phi_2|^2 - |\phi_3|^2 - |\phi_4|^2 =r
\end{align}
For $r>>0$ this vacua makes $\mathcal{O}(-1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)$ over $\mathbf{CP}^1$ where the base is $(\phi_1, \phi_2)$ and for $r<<0$ case vacua makes $\mathcal{O}(-1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)$ over $\mathbf{CP}^1$ where the base is $(\phi_3, \phi_4)$.

At this moment i got confused.

Can one say that the $T^{*}\mathbf{CP}^1 = \mathcal{O}(-1) \oplus \mathcal{O}(-1)$ over $\mathbf{CP}^1$ ?

Thanks.